# Cannot get data from SQL Server in VS2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Facing a problem when trying to get data from SQL Server to Visual Studio 2008 smartdevice application(.net 3.5). I connect to my SQL Server via  Data Connections in VS2008 (shows test connection is ok). After that I create DataSet where I drop necessary table from  Data Connections. Then I application form I put a Label which give value from my DataSet Table Adapter (I run that query in TableAdapter and it worked).

My code:

```
Public Class LOGIN

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim username As String
        Dim vardas As String

        Dim StkAdapter As DataSet1TableAdapters.SMN_BAL_WHZNBN_LOT_SRL_LVL_BAL1TableAdapter
        StkAdapter = New DataSet1TableAdapters.SMN_BAL_WHZNBN_LOT_SRL_LVL_BAL1TableAdapter

        username = "00-200-1482"
        vardas = StkAdapter.GetDataBy(SCANCODE:=username).Rows(0).Item("BAL_ZONDE_ID")

        Label1.Text = vardas

    End Sub


End Class
```

However, when i start debugging i immediately get  status "cannot find or open the pdb file" and then error message pops up "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame".. I have read that Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols i should tick "Microsoft Symbol Servers", but there is no record in that Symbols window and when i try to load from Microsoft Symbol Servers nothing loads...Thank you for a help in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7zb.png)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with SQL Server.   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=what+is+a+pdb+file&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=what+is+a+pdb+file&gs_l=hp...0l5.0.0.4.61482623...........0.Mqu3GBRhmI4

Comment: thank you, i will try fix that pdb problem, maybe it will help